# How to set number of threads as a downstream variable in PBS job queue

Tags: linux, bash, pbs

Is there any way to determine how many threads are available to a program when I run it from a PBS job script?

In the header of my PBS job script I set

```
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=8
```

Is there a command I can use that will detect the number of threads - so that I can set a variable to equal this number (for downstream processes).

This way I can set threads as `$k`, for downstream processes, instead of going through the code line by line every time I change `#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=_`.

---

Thanks all!
I found a workaround -
So if using a single node the variable I am looking for is $PBS_NUM_PPN

Comment: @jww - This makes more sense if you understand the context: PBS is Portable Batch System (or possibly Torque), and `#PBS` "comments" are how you specify scheduler parameters for your job.

Comment: @Stephen - Ack, thanks.

Comment: @Adi -- PBS is not part of bash itself, or a tool available on out-of-the-box Linux installs, and an overwhelming majority of bash (and Linux) users have no idea that it even exists. Thus, to get more clued-in answers (and fewer downvotes), it's helpful to emphasize the PBS part more than the bash or Linux parts when asking questions that relate to both; I've edited appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

By default, PBS doesn't expose the `ppn` setting in the running job.  And there is no way that a shell script can read its comments ... without knowing and parsing its source (and that's probably not going to work here for a couple of reasons.)

But here are a couple of ideas:

1. You could pass an arbitrary variable from the `qsub` command line using the `-v` option.  (You might be able to do the same thing using `#PBS -v ...` but would be equivalent to setting a variable in your script in the normal way.)
2. You should be able to specify the resources (using `-l`) on the `qsub` command line instead of in the job script.

Put them together like this:

```
qsub ... -l nodes=1:ppn=8 - v NOSTHREADS=8 myscript.pbs
```

where `myscript.pbs` is:

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS directives ... without the "-l" !!!

# ordinary shell commands.

somecommand --someoption $NOSTHREADS ...
```

Note: I recommend that you don't *mix* specifying resources on the command line and in the script.  Put the "-l" options in one place only.  If you put them in both places AND your Torque / PBS installation uses job submission filters, things can get rather confused.

---

Alternatively, you could write a shell (or python or whatever) launcher that *generates* the PBS script with matching values of the `ppn` (etc) resource(s) and the corresponding variable(s) embedded in the generated script.

This approach can have the advantage of being more reproducible ... if you do a few other things as well.  (Ask a local eResearch analyst about reproducibility in your scientific computing.)

---

If neither of the above can be made to work, you *might* be able to check the `ulimit` settings within the job script.  However, my understanding is that the PBS `mon` will typically not use ulimit restrictions as the means of enforcing thread / process limits.  Instead, it will monitor the number of cores that are active.  (The `ppn` resource limits the number of processors, not the number of threads or processes.)

Comment: I don't know PBS enough to speak to this with any certainty, and this probably falls within the "couple of reasons" you elided -- but at runtime, will `$BASH_SOURCE` refer back to a file with comments intact, or is PBS feeding the script to the shell via a FIFO or other mechanism that doesn't allow inspection of the linked file?

Comment: Good question!  I don't know.